# Python conditional replace

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, regular-language

I need conditional replace in string.

```
input_str = "a111a11b111b22"

condition : ("b" + any number + "b") to ("Z" + any number)

output_str = "a111a11Z11122"
```

maybe I need to use  `[0]` and `[-1]` for remove "b"s and "Z"+any number

but I can't find conditional replace for it.

Comment: Have you tried using the `regex` module?

Comment: Welcome to SO! `regex` is overkill, `re` seems sufficient: `re.sub(r"b(\d+)b", r"Z\1", s)`? When you say "any number" is that 1 number or 1 or more numbers? Also, please share what you tried.

Comment: Thanks! I need to learn regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). They are really useful:

```
import re
input_str = "a111a11b111b22"
output_str = re.sub(r'b(\d+)b', r'Z\1', input_str) 

# output_str is "a111a11Z11122"
```

The `r'b(\d+)b'` regexpr matches letter `b`, followed by 1 or more digits and other letter `b`. The parenthesis memorizes the digits for further use (with `\1`) in the replacement part of the sentence (letter `Z` and `\1`).

Comment: Thanks! I need to practice regular expressions :0 seems difficult

Answer (score 0):

Try with regex:

```
import re
input_str = "a111a11b111b22"
output_str = re.sub(r'[b](\d)',r'Z\1',input_str)
print(output_str)
```